# Spacing before Christmas tree trunk

Tags: java, for-loop

I have an exercise where I have to print a christmas tree.

```
    public class ChristmasTree {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int size = 6;
            printChristmasTree(size);
    }



 public static void printChristmasTree(int size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size - i; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < (2 * i + 1); j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++) {
            System.out.print("**");
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

What I get is:

```
      *
     ***
    *****
   *******
  *********
 ***********
**
```

How can I fix it? How should I change this loop to move that trunk to the center of that tree?

Comment: Add some spaces...?

Comment: I can't. I was told to "create loop for printing spaces before tree trunk"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
     for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++) {
        System.out.print("**");
        System.out.println();
     }
```

to

```
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print("**");
```

You need to loop to find number of spaces from size, and place it accordingly.  Adjust the loop variable k if it is off a bit.

Comment: it didn't help too much, trunk just moved two spaces to the right, it's not in the center

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood what size was, try again.  I changed it to k++

Answer (score 0):

You said christmass tree so I guessed that you want the tree trunk to be in different lines. If it's what you want it's the code here:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
    for (int l = 0; l <= size; l++) {
        if (l != size)
            System.out.print(" ");
        else
            System.out.println("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

If you want in the same line here you are:

```
    for (int l = 0; l <= size; l++) {
        if (l != size)
            System.out.print(" ");
        else
            System.out.print("**");
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: The line System.out.println(); needs to removed and System.out.println("*") should not have ln or else they will be placed on different lines.  This also prints a space in between the * in all cases.  Although other than those this should work.